# java comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, comparison

When doing a `Collection.sort using` a custom comparator I am getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract`

I understand that this is a problem due to the fact that the method is not transitive. In my comparator, multiple methods are called and I identified the piece of code which violates this rule. However I am not able to fix it nor see the problem with it.

```
private int compareInstancesBelowChangeNumberStructureElements(ISapInstance pInstance1,
ISapInstance pInstance2) {
// Sort algorithm below change number structure elements
    String[] tokens1 =     pInstance1.getName().asString().split(COMPOUND_NAME_DELIMITER_REGEX);
    String[] tokens2 =      pInstance2.getName().asString().split(COMPOUND_NAME_DELIMITER_REGEX);

    if ((tokens1 == null) || (tokens2 == null)) {
      return 0;
    }

     int minLength = tokens1.length;
     if (tokens2.length < minLength) {
      minLength = tokens2.length;
     }

    if (minLength < 3) {
      return 0;
    }

// Compare criterion 1: node name or assembly group name
int compareValue = tokens1[2].compareTo(tokens2[2]);
if ((compareValue == 0) && (minLength >= 4)) {
  // Compare criterion 2: class name
  compareValue = tokens1[3].compareTo(tokens2[3]);
  if (compareValue == 0) {
    // Compare criterion 3: pos var name or assembly position name
    compareValue = tokens1[1].compareTo(tokens2[1]);
    if (compareValue == 0) {
      // Compare criterion 4: instance name
      compareValue = tokens1[0].compareTo(tokens2[0]);
    }
  }
}
return compareValue;
  }
```

Comment: I don’t know why you removed all the code from your question, but please put it back.  The answers are useless and nonsensical without it.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison method violates the transitivity requirement if an `ISapInstance.getName()` has less than three tokens.

Say you have three instances of `ISapInstance`:

- a - with a name that has three token elements
- b - with a name that has two token elements
- c - with a name that has three token elements and whose `token[2]` value is different from that of a

Now if you call your comparison method with `a` and `b` or with `b` and `c`, the comparison method returns `0` for both calls.

To satisfy the transitivity rule, your comparison method must also return `0` if it is called with `a` and `c`. But since both have names with more than two tokens and different values for the `token[2]`  it will return something different from `0` if prepared like described.

---

The same problem arises with these three instances:

(all instances have the same values for token[2])

- a - with a name that has four token elements
- b - with a name that has three token elements
- c - with a name that has four token elements and whose `token[3]` value is different from that of a

---

To fix this, your comparator must not return `0` if only one of instances has less then three tokens or if the third token is the same and only one has exactly three tokens.

For example:

```
private int compareInstancesBelowChangeNumberStructureElements(ISapInstance pInstance1,
            ISapInstance pInstance2) {
    // Sort algorithm below change number structure elements
    String[] tokens1 =     pInstance1.getName().asString().split(COMPOUND_NAME_DELIMITER_REGEX);
    String[] tokens2 =      pInstance2.getName().asString().split(COMPOUND_NAME_DELIMITER_REGEX);

    if (tokens1.length < 3) {
        return (tokens2.length < 3) ? 0 : -1;
    } else if (tokens2.length < 3) {
        return 1;
    }
    int minLength = tokens1.length;
    if (tokens2.length < minLength) {
        minLength = tokens2.length;
    }

    // Compare criterion 1: node name or assembly group name
    int compareValue = tokens1[2].compareTo(tokens2[2]);
    if (compareValue == 0) {
        if (tokens1.length < 4) {
            return (token2.length < 4) ? -1 : 0;
        } else if (tokens2.length < 4) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            // ... the remaining comparison operations
        }
    }
    return compareValue;
}
```

Comment: I tried something similar and it would still fail, from my debugging it was starting from // Compare criterion 1: node name or assembly group name

Comment: Just tried it again, it still fails, that was not the problem

Comment: @patentul I've updated my explanation and my sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine situation where `ISapInstances` have next amount of tokens.

```
a -> 4
b -> 2
c -> 4
```

It leads to `a = b` and `b = c` (because `minLength` is `2`), so `a` must be equal to `c`, but it is not necessary true if we compare `a` and `c` directly.

Comment: Typing from phone, please format my answer property if you like it.

Comment: Format it properly yourself. This is not a typing service.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the length checks are causing this problem and if you are checking lengths to avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsExcpetion`. There is another way that don't involve the length checks.

```
static class Tokens implements Comparable<Tokens> {
    private static final int N = 4;
    // Order in which we would like to compare the tokens.
    private static final int [] TOKEN_POS = {2, 3, 1, 0};

    // Reordered tokens
    private final String [] tokens = new String[N];

    // The comparator used to compare each token
    private final Comparator<String> cmp = Comparator.nullsFirst(String::compareTo);

    Tokens(String []tokens) {
        int i = 0;
        for (int p : TOKEN_POS) {
            // Place token to it's *correct* position
            // put null if tokens does not have enough elements
            this.tokens[i++] = p < tokens.length ? tokens[p] : null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Tokens o) {
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int c = cmp.compare(tokens[i], o.tokens[i]);
            if (c != 0) return c;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Tokens{" +
                "tokens=" + Arrays.toString(tokens) +
                '}';
    }
}

private static Tokens getCompareKey(String [] tokens) {
    return new Tokens(tokens);
}

private static void compareAndPrint(Tokens k1, Tokens k2) {
    System.out.println(k1 + " cmp " + k2 + " = " + k1.compareTo(k2));
}

public static void main(String [] args) {
    Tokens key1 = getCompareKey(new String[]{"1", "2", "3"});
    Tokens key2 = getCompareKey(new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "5"});
    Tokens key3 = getCompareKey(new String[]{"1", "3"});
    compareAndPrint(key2, key1);
    compareAndPrint(key1, key3);
    compareAndPrint(key2, key3);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Tokens{key=[3, 5, 2, 1]} cmp Tokens{key=[3, null, 2, 1]} = 1
Tokens{key=[3, null, 2, 1]} cmp Tokens{key=[null, null, 3, 1]} = 1
Tokens{key=[3, 5, 2, 1]} cmp Tokens{key=[null, null, 3, 1]} = 1
```

It's obvious that this way the ordering is transitive. However it does compare the tokens down to the last one. You can decide whether it's a suitable ordering for your application.